# Using Selenium Webdriver gives login details Incorrect even though its correct

Tags: selenium, webdriver, automated-tests

Hi I am trying to automated testing for a log in page for a website. I have entered correct username and password but the program returns back saying the username or Password is incorrect, While I copy and paste the user name and password manually it logs me in.  Following is the program code :

```
<?php
namespace Facebook\WebDriver;

use Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\DesiredCapabilities;
use Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver;

require_once('vendor/autoload.php');

$host = 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub'; 
$capabilities = DesiredCapabilities::chrome();
$driver = RemoteWebDriver::create($host, $capabilities, 5000);

// navigate to 'http://www.seleniumhq.org/'
$driver->get('https:www.abcd.com'); // I had to hide this for security purpose

// adding cookie
$driver->manage()->deleteAllCookies();

$cookie = new Cookie('cookie_name', 'cookie_value');
$driver->manage()->addCookie($cookie);

$cookies = $driver->manage()->getCookies();
print_r($cookies);

$email =$driver->findElement(WebDriverBy::id('textfield-1017-inputEl'));
$email->sendKeys("scott"); 

$password= $driver->findElement(WebDriverBy::id('textfield-1018-inputEl'));
$password->sendKeys("abcd123") ;

$login = $driver->findElement(WebDriverBy::id('button-1021-btnInnerEl'));
$login->click() ;
// wait at most 10 seconds until at least one result is shown
$driver->wait(10)->until(
    WebDriverExpectedCondition::presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(
        WebDriverBy::className('gsc-result')
        )
    );


$driver->quit();

?>
```

Comment: Please confirm the username and password text filed is bind validation function to check illegal letter or else.

Comment: thanks fo the commnet, that was not the case in this instance

Answer (score 1):

You should wait until the first field is filled before filling the second field. I noticed this on very slow machines where code execution is faster than browser execution.

The text for the first field is written into the browser buffer but not entirely written to the control of the browser. Then the code execution continues and sets the buffer target to the next input control. So rest of the buffer is wrongly written into the next input control.

If this applies you only have to count the actual chars of any of your input fields and compare its lengths to the expected lengths.

Comment: Thank for the comment.